# Multiple Havings not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, having, iif-function

I have a database with the following schema:

```
ID   PositionId    LeagueId
1        4            5
3        4            5
3        8            5
4        1            6
```

I have this sql query in Access:

```
 SELECT lp.PositionId
 FROM Leagues l 
 INNER JOIN Lineups lp ON (l.LeagueID = lp.LeagueId) 
 GROUP BY PositionId
 HAVING sum(iif(lp.PositionId = 4,1,0)) > 1 AND sum(iif(lp.PositionId = 8,1,0)) > 0
```

If I only use the left side of the Having, ie:

```
 HAVING sum(iif(lp.PositionId = 4,1,0)) > 1
```

I will get 1 results (LeagueId 5).  If I use the right-side of the Having, ie:

```
 HAVING sum(iif(lp.PositionId = 8,1,0)) > 0
```

I will also get one result (LeagueId 5), but both together (like above) yields no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because the SUM can't satisfy both HAVING predicates, so try using an OR:

```
  SELECT lp.PositionId
    FROM Leagues l 
    JOIN Lineups lp ON (l.LeagueID = lp.LeagueId) 
GROUP BY PositionId
  HAVING SUM(iif(lp.PositionId = 4,1,0)) > 1 OR SUM(iif(lp.PositionId = 8,1,0)) > 0
```

Comment: +1 - You are basically saying "Show me the rows with position 4 AND position 8", which can't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you grouping by positionid? So for each positionid you're asking the sum for that positionid to be >0 when the id is 4 AND 8 at the same time. Is this possible? Do you want an OR? Should you be using a different query?

`GROUP BY LeagueID`, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a much simplified version of this query e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 8 AS PositionId
  FROM Lineups 
 WHERE PositionId = 8 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 4
  FROM Lineups 
 WHERE PositionId = 4
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```